# Context cannot be converted to Tab1Values

Tags: android, fragment, phone-state-listener

I have this problem as I said at title with the above code.The error it is at the line that I have the arrow.Probably the problem is because of the `extends Fragment` because this code before I put it there it was at an Activity and it works fine.Please tell me what to change.

Tab1Values.java

```
public class Tab1Values extends Fragment {
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
    int value=0,dbm=0;
    String ptype="",ntype="";
    public Tab1Values() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info);
        tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info2);
        tv3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info3);
        TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(new Tab1Signal(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext()), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        return v;
    }

    public void data(int value1,int value2){
        tv2.setText("GsmBitErrorRate:"+value1+" \nGsmSignalStrength:"+value2);
    }
    public void test(int LteSignalStrength,int LteRsrp,int LteRsrq,int LteRssnr,int LteCqi){
        tv3.setText("\nLteSignalStrength:"+dbm+" dbm"+
                "\nLteRsrp: "+LteRsrp+
                "\nLteRsrq: "+LteRsrq+
                "\nLteRssnr: "+LteRssnr+
                "\nLteCqi: "+ LteCqi);
    }
```

Tab1Signal.java

```
public class Tab1Signal extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context mcontext;
    int LteSignalStrength=0,LteRsrp=0,LteRsrq=0,LteRssnr=0,LteCqi=0;
    int value1=0,value2=0,CdmaDbm=0,CdmaEcio=0,EvdoDbm=0,EvdoEcio=0,EvdoSnr=0;
    //int cid=0,lac=0,psc=0,statid=0,netid=0,sysid=0,lat=0,lon=0;
    String error,ss,val1,ccloc;
    private Tab1Values main;

    public Tab1Signal(Context context){
        mcontext=context;
        ->main=(Tab1Values) mcontext;
    }
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength){
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        if (signalStrength.isGsm()) {
            value1=signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate();
            value2=signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        }else if (signalStrength.getCdmaDbm() > 0) {
            CdmaDbm=signalStrength.getCdmaDbm();
            CdmaEcio=signalStrength.getCdmaEcio();
        } else {
            EvdoDbm=signalStrength.getEvdoDbm();
            EvdoEcio=signalStrength.getEvdoEcio();
            EvdoSnr=signalStrength.getEvdoSnr();
        }
        try {
            Method[] methods = android.telephony.SignalStrength.class
                    .getMethods();
            for (Method mthd : methods) {
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteSignalStrength")){
                    //val1=mthd.getName() ;
                    LteSignalStrength=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                    //main.test(val2);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrp")){
                    LteRsrp=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRsrq")){
                    LteRsrq=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteRssnr")){
                    LteRssnr=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                if (mthd.getName().equals("getLteCqi")){
                    LteCqi=(Integer)mthd.invoke(signalStrength);
                }
                main.test(LteSignalStrength,LteRsrp,LteRsrq,LteRssnr,LteCqi);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`, and `Fragment` is not. One easy way to fix this is to change the constructor of your `Tab1Signal` to take in `Tab1Values` as parameter:

```
public Tab1Signal(Tab1Values fragment){
    mcontext = fragment.getContext();
    main = fragment;
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask you if there is a way to take as parameter 2 different classes and pass data to them?Thank you

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.. Did you say if you could do something like `public Tab1Signal(Tab1Values fragment, Object someArguments) {`?

Comment: No if I can do `public Tab1Signal(Tab1Values fragment, Tab2 fragment2)`.Actually I did that but didn't work and I wonder if there is other way?

Comment: Right, it's pretty much the same thing, you can pass in whatever you want to. But just be careful with context leaks because fragments carry them, and also what is your purpose for having those fragments Tab1Signal?

Comment: I want to show the same data for the lte quality into a map according the location.Thank you for your help